Not Recieving any Accessibility Event at all
I'm not Recieving any Accessibility Event when app is minimized (in android 14) but it works fine in android 10
Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    
    
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="CrashActivity" />
        <service
            android:name="ScreenshotService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection"
            android:permission="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


        <service
            android:name="MyAccessibilityService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
        </service>


    </application>
</manifest>


Accessibility service:
package aman.astau;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "accessibility_service_channel";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Create the notification channel
        createNotificationChannel();
        // Create a persistent notification
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Accessibility Service")
                .setContentText("The service is running in the background")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .build();
        
        // Start the service in the foreground
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "something happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // Handle interruptions (e.g., if the service is turned off)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "interrupted" , 0).show();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Accessibility Service Channel";
            String description = "Channel for accessibility service";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            // Register the channel with the system
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }
}

Config
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:notificationTimeout="1000"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description" />

I want it work like it worked in android 10
One thing to note - "Mt manager" or "current Activity" etc apps are able to display the whole class names of app

It's my own question, so the problem is that code was(is) working fine for the purpose, but back then I relied on toast message for logging it worked in android 10 but in android 14, I guess toast message aren't displayed when application is minimised , afterwards I used Log for checking and found it that it is already working fine.
TL;DR - use Log instead of Toast
